# Simplifying the boolean expression $Y = (A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot \overline{F})+(A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot E) + (A \cdot F) $

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

for the past hours, I have been simplifying a huge boolean expression.  There is only one short piece missing, which, for the love of god, I can not manage to simplify.

The term is:

$$
Y = (A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot \overline{F})+(A\cdot B \cdot C \cdot E) + (A \cdot F)
$$

Now, factoring out $A\cdot B \cdot C$ gives:

$$
Y = (A\cdot F)+(A\cdot B \cdot C)\cdot (\overline{F}+ E)
$$

I have computed the simplest form of the expression to be:

$$
Y = (A \cdot B \cdot C)+(A \cdot F)
$$

My guess is, to obtain the result, $(\overline{F}\cdot E)$ will need to be $1$. Now for that to happen, either $\overline{F}$ or $E$ will need to become 1. I assume, that would be somehow done by building the complement of $F$ and $\overline{F}$.

Thanks in advance! Apologies, if this is trivial and I'm just being dense.

Comment: Isn´t there a typo? $E$ on both sides of the given identity looks strange.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks for noticing! That made no sense at all... I guess, I just chose "E" as in "expression" without thinking about the variable.

Comment: $Y = (A \cdot B \cdot C)+(A \cdot F)$ is the simplest if $E=F.$ In general, the simplest DNF form is $A\cdot F+A\cdot C\cdot E+A\cdot \overline{B}\cdot C.$